# Android setVisibility does not work on some logic

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Just a little introduction of what I am doing.

I am granting different functionality based on the account type a user has sign in with.

The user's account type will be retrieved via Firebase Reference from Firebase Database. If you look at this image, there's the arrow indicated. That is where the account type will be displayed but to consider the UI, I have set the visibility of the text view to be "gone". I have validated that the database reference codes are working as when I set the visibility of the text view to be visible, and then I run the app, the text view will change accordingly to be either Administrator or Local User.

[image]

The problem lies on my setVisibility 'if else' logic. It does not work accordingy. Attached are the list of scenarios I have tested and the outcomes of it.

[image]

I have tried adding the visibility to 'gone' on my pencil icon, and use VISIBILE/INVISIBLE/GONE without the View infront of it (like what many have said as their solution on several similar posts), but when I tried that, the icon is **invisible** for all 8 scenarios.

As such, I am not sure what else I should do to overcome this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

**Update #1: Added codes as requested**

```
class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView keyword, description, acronym, relatedkeyword1, 
relatedkeyword2, relatedkeyword3, tv_rules_read_more;
public ImageView iv_rules;

public SearchViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    //knowledge feature
    keyword = itemView.findViewById(R.id.keyword);
    acronym = itemView.findViewById(R.id.acronym);
    tv_rules_read_more = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rules_read_more);
    iv_rules = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_rules);
}
}

public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder> 
implements SectionIndexer {

//    private Context context;
private List<Knowledge> knowledge;
private ArrayList<Integer> mSectionPositions;
Activity activity;
String positionUpdated;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

public SearchAdapter(Activity activity, List<Knowledge> knowledge, String 
positionUpdated) {
    //this.context = context;
    this.knowledge = knowledge;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.positionUpdated = positionUpdated;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
    return new SearchViewHolder(itemView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder holder, final int 
position) {

    holder.keyword.setText(knowledge.get(position).getKeyword());
    holder.acronym.setText(knowledge.get(position).getAcronym());
    holder.tv_rules_read_more.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showDialog(position);
        }
    });
    if (positionUpdated != null && !positionUpdated.equals("")) {
        showDialog(Integer.parseInt(positionUpdated));
        positionUpdated = "";
    }

}

public void showDialog(final int position) {

    try {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout_item_rules);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        final TextView acctype, keyword1, description1, acronym1, 
        relatedkeyword4, relatedkeyword5, relatedkeyword6;
        //final TextView keyword1, description1, acronym1, 
        relatedkeyword4, relatedkeyword5, relatedkeyword6;
        ImageView iv_rules, iv_close_dialog, iv_edit_dialog;

        //rules feature
        acctype = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvAccType);
        keyword1 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.keyword);
        acronym1 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.acronym);
        description1 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.description);
        relatedkeyword4 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.relatedKeyword1);
        relatedkeyword5 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.relatedKeyword2);
        relatedkeyword6 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.relatedKeyword3);
        iv_rules = dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_rules);
        iv_close_dialog = dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_close_dialog);
        iv_edit_dialog = dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_edit_dialog);

        /////////
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = 
        firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UserProfile userProfile = 
        dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
                acctype.setText(userProfile.getUserDepartment());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) 
       {
            }
        });

        if (acctype.getText().toString().equals("Administrator")){
            iv_edit_dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            iv_edit_dialog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        ////////

        keyword1.setText(knowledge.get(position).getKeyword());
        description1.setText(knowledge.get(position).getDescription());
        acronym1.setText(knowledge.get(position).getAcronym());

relatedkeyword4.setText(knowledge.get(position).getRelatedkeyword1());

relatedkeyword5.setText(knowledge.get(position).getRelatedkeyword2());

relatedkeyword6.setText(knowledge.get(position).getRelatedkeyword3());
        byte[] bytesImage = knowledge.get(position).getImage();
        if (bytesImage != null && bytesImage.length > 0) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytesImage, 0, 
bytesImage.length);
            iv_rules.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            iv_rules.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            iv_rules.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        dialog.show();
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new 
WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        layoutParams.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
        layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        window.setAttributes(layoutParams);

        iv_close_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        iv_edit_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, 
AddNewKnowledgeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", 
String.valueOf(knowledge.get(position).getId()));
                intent.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position));
                intent.putExtra("call_type", "update_rule");
                intent.putExtra("title", 
knowledge.get(position).getKeyword());
                intent.putExtra("code", 
knowledge.get(position).getAcronym());
                intent.putExtra("description", 
knowledge.get(position).getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("keyword1", 
knowledge.get(position).getRelatedkeyword1());
                intent.putExtra("keyword2", 
knowledge.get(position).getRelatedkeyword2());
                intent.putExtra("keyword3", 
knowledge.get(position).getRelatedkeyword3());
                intent.putExtra("bytesImage", 
knowledge.get(position).getImage());
                dialog.cancel();
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return knowledge.size();
}


@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object[] getSections() {
    List<String> sections = new ArrayList<>(26);
    mSectionPositions = new ArrayList<>(26);
    for (int i = 0, size = knowledge.size(); i < size; i++) {
        String section = 
String.valueOf(knowledge.get(i).getKeyword().charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
        if (!sections.contains(section)) {
            sections.add(section);
            mSectionPositions.add(i);
        }
    }
    return sections.toArray(new String[0]);
}

@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex) {
    return mSectionPositions.get(sectionIndex);
}
}
```

**Update 2: Added XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="#f5f0f0"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
app:cardElevation="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_rules"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@color/deeppurpleColor"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_edit_dialog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_close_dialog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAccType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Account Type"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/keyword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:text="Baggage Management Interface Device (BMID) 
Testing 123"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/codeHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:text="Code:"
                android:textColor="#a8000000"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/acronym"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:text="GST"
                android:textColor="#a8000000"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ruleHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:text="Desc:"
                android:textColor="#a8000000"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="If none are set then 'GST' is set to NULL"
                android:textColor="#a8000000"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/relatedKeyword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:text="Related Keyword:"
                android:textColor="#a8000000"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/relatedKeyword1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Keyword 1,"
                android:textColor="#a8000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/relatedKeyword2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Keyword 2,"
                android:textColor="#a8000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/relatedKeyword3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Keyword 3"
                android:textColor="#a8000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Please provide some code to look into. Theoretically everything looks fine.

Comment: The last scenario threw me off a bit, but it seems like your `accType` text view doesn't contain the correct text. Could you check this out, or post the relevant parts of coffee so we can help please? Especially since where the arrow points there's no account type, it really sounds like you've missed this part

Comment: @Wijdan I have added my codes, please check

Comment: @Fred I have checked that my accType does contain the correct value as retrieved from and referenced to firebase database. It is setVisibility to gone as I don't really want the text itself to appear on the dialog.

Comment: Did you set the visibility attribute in the xml file? Also make sure by toasting that your conditions are working.

Comment: From the scenario list, I could only make out your condition always returns false except in last scenario which always returns true. Kindly check what value you are getting in "acctype". Also I would suggest to use equalIgnoreCase instead of equals and check.

Comment: @Wijdan I have tried to set the visibility of the pencil icon to gone and invisible on both the java & xml class. But when I do so, the pencil icon does not appear on all 8 scenarios.

Comment: This means that when setting gone from xml makes them invisible and your conditions for setting it to visible are not executing. Kindly add a toast or log in every  if else condition and check which of them are executing according to your scenarios.

Comment: `Kindly add a toast or log in every if else condition` Please no, just no! Instead the best way to understand the code is to debug it with the debugger. At the beginning of your visibility logic you add a breakpoint, start the app with the debugger attached and then go line by line and evaluate before you step over that line what you expect the next line to be and why. As soon as you find the debugger doing something unexpected, you very likely found your flaw in the logic. Help can be found here: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+debug+android+app+in+android+studio (videos, tutorials...)

Comment: @Wijdan So do I set the visibility of the pencil icon to gone/invisible in the xml file or not? Sure, I will try to toast / add log and then update the post again.

Comment: Its better to set them to gone/invisible once your conditions are working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by placing the if/else logic inside `onDataChange` method!

The logic did not work accordingly as my if/else logic were placed outside of the loop. The logic should work while Firebase is retrieving then displaying the values.

As such, instead of these:

```
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = 
    firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserProfile userProfile = 
    dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
            acctype.setText(userProfile.getUserDepartment());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) 
   {
        }
    });

    //note: these are outside of the loop at first
    if (acctype.getText().toString().equals("Administrator")){
        iv_edit_dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        iv_edit_dialog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

It should be like this instead:

```
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UserProfile userProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
                acctype.setText(userProfile.getUserDepartment());

                //granting different functionality based on account type
                if (acctype.getText().toString().equals("Administrator")){
                    iv_edit_dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else {
                    iv_edit_dialog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

I learnt my lesson the hard way! It is **very** important to understand the logic you want to come out with, followed by the expected work flow!

Many thanks to those who have taken their time to guide me through!